# Not able to extract particular field from "MBRecognitionResult*" in BlinkIDUI-iOS sdk?

Tags: microblink

I am using your new BlinkIDUI sdk for iOS and I can have the list of all the scanned fields from **"recognitionResult.resultEntries"** like Secondary ID = Jason", "Primary ID = Bourne", "Sex = F", "Date Of Birth = 3/23/83", "Nationality = UAE", "Document Code = P" from the delegate method "**- (void)didScanEntireDocumentWithRecognitionResult:(MBRecognitionResult * _Nonnull)recognitionResult successFrame:(UIImage * _Nullable)successFrame**". **My query is How to get value for particular key like “"Document Code” ?**

Additional Details are: 
The Framework addition in Project: Manual.
Xcode version : 10.1.
Language: Objective-C (ARC OFF).
Device: iPhone8 / iOS(11.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

That's because resultEntries is an array not a dictionary,
Use like this:

for (MBField *field in recognitionResult.resultEntries) {
        if (field.key == MBFieldKeyDocumentCode) {

```
    }
```

}

If you are using it in ObjectiveC project then also check if **@objc** tag is there in front of **MBFieldKey public property in "MBField" class**, if it is not there just put it as:

public class MBField: NSObject {

```
@objc public let key: MBFieldKey

@objc public let value: String
```

.....
}